# Symfony2 Looping Same field in form

Tags: forms, loops, symfony

I have a problem in symfony2 form.
I have a same field in a form. I create one by one by changing the name.

```
    $formBuilderUpload = $this->createFormBuilder()->setAction($this->generateUrl('bsi_bkpm_backend_uploadfile_create'));

    $formBuilder = $formBuilderUpload;

        $formBuilder->add('file_1','file', array('required'=> false, 'label'=> 'File 1'))
                ->add('filename_1' , 'text',  array(
                    'required' => false,
                        'label' => 'Subject 1'
                    ))
                ->add('description_1','text',array('required'=> false, 'label'=>' Description 1'))

                ->add('file_2','file', array('required'=> false, 'label'=> 'File 2'))
                ->add('filename_2' , 'text',  array(
                    'required' => false,
                        'label' => 'Subject 2'))
                ->add('description_2','text',array('required'=> false, 'label'=>' Description 2'))                                

                ->add('file_3','file', array('required'=> false, 'label'=> 'File 2'))
                ->add('filename_3' , 'text',  array(
                    'required' => false,
                        'label' => 'Subject 3'))
                ->add('description_3','text',array('required'=> false, 'label'=>' Description 4'))            

                ->add('file_4','file', array('required'=> false, 'label'=> 'File 2'))
                ->add('filename_4' , 'text',  array(
                    'required' => false,
                        'label' => 'Subject 4'))
                ->add('description_4','text',array('required'=> false, 'label'=>' Description 4'))                                

                ->add('file_5','file', array('required'=> false, 'label'=> 'File 5'))
                ->add('filename_5' , 'text',  array(
                    'required' => false,
                        'label' => 'Subject 5'))
                ->add('description_5','text',array('required'=> false, 'label'=>' Description 5'))            

                // add submit button
                ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    //Create the form
    $form = $formBuilder->getForm();
    return $form;
```

But I want the code become efficient by looping it. Does anyone know how to looping it?

Best regards,

hendrawan

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you explain it better? What code do you need?

Comment: I want to make a multiple file upload using symfony form and adding some other text field such subject, and description. I want to make them as one variable name array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a pretty easy one, just loop over a for loop like so...

```
$limit = 5;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $limit; $i++) {
    $builder
        ->add('file_'.$i, 'file', array(
            'required'  => false, 
            'label'     => 'File '.$i,
        ))
        ->add('filename_'.$i, 'text',  array(
            'required'  => false,
            'label'     => 'Subject '.$i,
        ))
        ->add('description_'.$i, 'text', array(
            'required'  => false, 
            'label'     => 'Description '.$i,
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: yeah you right.. that solved my problem, Thanks Qoop. I had tried to looping at first time but failed. That's why I ask. But maybe you can help me, how to change the parameter name to become one array?